# Putting a Jekyll site into a minimalist CMS

Tags: php, cms, markdown, wysiwyg, jekyll

I built a site using Jekyll for my wife's coworker a while back.
It's a simple site, three pages of text/images plus a Contact Us page calling a PHP script to send an email.

Now, she wants a way to edit it herself. She's not technically inclined in the slightest, so giving her the Jekyll site would be pointless.

What I'm looking for is the most minimal kind of CMS so she can

- Log in as admin
- Add/Remove pages (tabs) from the site
- Have some sort of WYSIWYG editor for the main `<div>` on each page
- The look and feel of the current site is left unaffected.

and that's basically all that's needed.

It's running on a cheap web host that only does PHP and a MySQL database. I've thought about just writing my own and giving it to her, but I'd really like to just be done with things at this point. I don't want to write any more code for this.

Is there anything out there that meets these requirements?

Comment: Does the host include support for MySQL?

Comment: Yes, technically MariaDB, but yes.